# Is there any wrapper for OpenCV for .net core on linux

Tags: opencv, .net-core

I would like to use an OpenCV from my .net core console application on Ubuntu 16.04.
Is there any wrapper for OpenCV I can use from .net core app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up with [OpenCvSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp), it fills my requirements.